# Subset two consecutive event occurrence in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, time-series

I'm trying to get a subset of my data whenever there is consecutive occurrence of an two events in that order. The event is time-stamped. So every time there are continuous 2's and then continuous 3's, I want to subset that to a dataframe and append it to a dictionary. The following code does that but I have to apply this to a very large dataframe of more than 20 mil obs. This is extremely slow using iterrows. How can I make this fast?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': [101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122],
        'Event': [1,1,2,2,2,3,3,1,3,2,2,3,1,2,3,2,3,2,2,3,3,3]})

dfb = pd.DataFrame(columns = df.columns)
C = {}
f1 = 0

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if ((row['Event'] == 2) & (3 not in dfb['Event'].values)):
        dfb = dfb.append(row)
        f1 =1
    elif ((row['Event'] == 3) & (f1 == 1)):
        dfb = dfb.append(row)
    elif 3 in dfb['Event'].values:
        f1 = 0
        C[str(dfb.iloc[0,0])] = dfb
        del dfb
        dfb = pd.DataFrame(columns = df.columns)
        if row['Event'] == 2:
            dfb = dfb.append(row)
            f1 =1
    else:
        f1=0
        del dfb
        dfb = pd.DataFrame(columns = df.columns)
```

Edit: The desired output is basically a dictionary of the subsets shown in the imagehttps://i.stack.imgur.com/ClWZs.png

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to accerlate, you should vectorize your code. You could try it like this (df is the same with your code):

```
vec = df.copy()
vec['Event_y'] = vec['Event'].shift(1).fillna(0).astype(int)
vec['Same_Flag'] = float('nan')
vec.Same_Flag.loc[(vec['Event_y'] == vec['Event']) & (vec['Event'] != 1)] = 1
vec.dropna(inplace=True)
vec.loc[:, ('Date', 'Event')]
```

Output is:

> Date    Event
> 3   104 2
> 4   105 2
> 6   107 3
> 10  111 2
> 18  119 2
> 20  121 3
> 21  122 3

I think that's close to what you need. You could improve based on that.

2. I'm not understand why date `104, 105, 107` are not counted.

Comment: Sorry, this is not the same as my output. Please see the image link in my question for the desired output.

Comment: Yes. I know that. So as I said, `I think that's close to what you need. You could improve based on that.`

Comment: Basically, they are the same meaning, but my answer is without the flag of yesterday's date. You could add yesterday's date to it, then they're the same.